# For each worksheets not working to print pdf

Tags: excel, vba

I'm printing some PDF from my Excel thanks to a little program, which was working and is not anymore and I can't figure out why. it's telling me

> error '5' argument or procedure call incorrect.

I think it's really a stupid mistake but I have the nose in it and can't find it.

N.B. The filename part is not the issue, I have the same result when I change it for a basic thing like "bob"

```
Sub impression_multiple_pdf()
Dim chaine As String
Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 If WS.Name <> "Tampon" And WS.Name <> "data" And WS.Name <> "Tableau de 
 Bord" Then
        WS.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, 
        Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Fiches Projet\Fiche Projet " & 
        clear_name(WS.Range("C3")), Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, 
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
End If
Next

ThisWorkbook.Activate
MsgBox "Fiches projet enregistrées dans mes documents"

End Sub
```

Clear name function :

```
Function clear_name(txt)
Dim C

 C = Array("<", ">", "?", "[", "]", ":", "*", "\", "/", "|", ".", "#", "€", 
",", "§", "@")
 'txt = Range("A2")

 For n = 0 To UBound(C)
     txt = Left(Trim(txt), 128)
     txt = Replace(txt, C(n), "")
 Next

 clear_name = txt

End Function
```

Comment: Make sure of the sheets names in this line `If WS.Name <> "Tampon" And WS.Name <> "data" And WS.Name <> "Tableau de 
 Bord" Then`

Comment: In which line does the error occur? Check your line breaks there are some underscores `_` for line concatenation missing. Also please [edit] and include the code of `clear_name`.

Comment: @YasserKhalil I tried removing entirely the condition, the error still occure.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I edited wih the function, the error occur on the WS.ExportasfixedFormat... line. The underscores issue are in my copy past on the post but are good in the code

Comment: What is the result of `clear_name(WS.Range("C3"))` in case of error? Go through your code step by step using F8 and check the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `clear_name(WS.Range("C3"))` is not empty.
Also make sure `ThisWorkbook.Path` returns a value that means your workbook needs to be saved at least once. And make sure your path exists `\Fiches Projet\Fiche Projet` otherwise it fails.

```
Sub impression_multiple_pdf()
    Dim chaine As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Filename As String

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> "Tampon" And WS.Name <> "data" And WS.Name <> "Tableau de Bord" Then
            Filename = clear_name(WS.Range("C3"))
            If Filename <> "" Then
                WS.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                   Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Fiches Projet\Fiche Projet " & Filename, _
                   Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                   IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                   OpenAfterPublish:=False
            Else
                MsgBox "Filename in '" & WS.Name & "' was empty"
            End If
       End If
    Next WS

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    MsgBox "Fiches projet enregistrées dans mes documents"
End Sub
```

If this doesn't help use

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Fiches Projet\Fiche Projet " & Filename
```

right after the line `Filename = clear_name(WS.Range("C3"))` and tell the result that is printed in the Immediate Window.

Comment: It's working ! Really weird though, I had to change the name of the sheets that are present in the If comparison and it worked.

Anyway thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @Guillaume This what I suggested in the first comment :) 
Glad it is solved

Comment: @YasserKhalil Well the name were the same that the sheets it was good, but not working, really weird :/ but i should have dug more in ur suggestion for sure ! thank for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Try editing this part

```
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Fiches Projet\Fiche Projet " & clear_name(ws.Range("C3")), Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Comment: Are the lines appear in your VBE as red color?!
Give an example of what is in the range C3 `ws.Range("C3")`

Comment: Nop, just in yellow when it's in debbug but no red

Comment: I mean in normal state not in the state of Debug. Try to put the lines in one line as I edited the post.

Comment: it's some basic text in C3, (but i tried changing it with juste a "name" and it changed nothing), in normal state everything is black